# Group results in Crystal Reports where linked column has multiple related results

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I have two tables that are linked.  The first table is a list of prescribed medications ('medications' table) and the other is a list of actions that relate to the medication when it has been prescribed ('PMP' table)

For each prescribed medication, there can be multiple actions such as authorise, comment, stop etc.
What i am trying to do is to call all prescribed medications along with every other action for that drug.

I can do this using the code below.

```
select medications.oid, medications.drug, PMP.action_dte, PMP.actions 
from medications
left join PMP on medications.oid = PMP.fk2_oid
```

This works fine and i get everything i need.  But the medications that have multiple actions are returned once for each action.

My issue comes when i want to put it in to a Crystal Report.
I have a subreport called Drugs and i want to list all of the authorised drugs on the left and then all the actions for that drug on the right.  But what i get is.

```
OID  |    MEDICATION      |   ACTION DTE  |    ACTION  
     |                    |               |
 1   | Paracetamol 200mg  |   01.01.17    |  Authorised
     |                    |               |
     |                    |               |
 1   | Paracetamol 200mg  |   03.01.17    |  Comment
     |                    |               |
     |                    |               |
 1   | Paracetamol 200mg  |   10.01.17    |   Stop
     |                    |               |
     |                    |               |
 2   |Ibuprofen 100mg     |   05.01.17    |  Authorised
     |                    |               |
     |                    |               |
 2   |Ibuprofen 100mg     |   06.02.17    |   Comment
```

Where as i would like

```
 OID   |   MEDICATION      |   ACTION DTE  |    ACTION
       |                   |               |
  1    | Paracetamol 200mg |   01.01.17    |  Authorised
       |                   |   03.01.17    |  Comment
       |                   |   10.01.17    |   Stop
       |                   |               |
  2    |  Ibuprofen 100mg  |   05.01.17    |  Authorised
       |                   |   06.02.17    |   Comment
       |                   |               |
```

I have played around with grouping by oid and fk2_oid.  As well as trying to link two sub reports on those fields but i am getting no where.

Is anyone able to suggest a formula or preferably a modification to the code which will allow the crystal report to display the drug on the left ONCE along with every action related to that drug on the right.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT ----------

I forgot to mention that there is a date field in the equation.  Which is PMP.action_dte.  Edited the original query and description.

Apologies for any confusion caused.

EDIT 2 ---------

Apparently my original post was misleading.....modified to hopefully clarify.  I would like the drug grouped by OID with every action allocated to that drug listed along with the action date, as shown above.

Comment: Yes but drug start date doesn't matter because i have managed to extract it and display it with no problems.  My problem is with displaying the drug as a group when there are multiple actions against it, instead of displaying the drug name for each action.  Start date you see here was for illustration purposes.  It was to illustrate that the drug was in fact the same drug for all actions, prescribed on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bring in your results
- Under Report > Group Expert, group by Drug.
- Then I deleted Drug in Details
- In Group Header 1, Section Report, check on Underlay Following
  Section
- Remove Bold for Group #1 Medication

You can download the [Crystal Report here](https://github.com/sunk818/crystal/raw/master/BringGroupToDetailLevel/drugs.rpt)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - When i run this with my actual data and field names i get the error "This field name is not known".  What exactly is meant by field name, i take it not the column names from the data extraction.

Comment: Also - There may actually be instances where the drug name is the same but there are different start dates and actions.  If for example someone was prescribed the same drug, then it stopped, then it started again.  So is this intended to be used on an OID field?

Comment: Not really.  Someone can be started and stopped on the same drug multiple times.  So i wouldnt want to group by drug name because Paracetamol 500mg could be prescribed to the same patient multiple times over a given time period.  So i would need to group by the OID of the drug entry in the medications table, which will be different for every prescription.  But then the actions against each individual prescription will be different with different start dates per action.  I think that was covered in my edit and examples of what i get and what i need at in the OP

Comment: No im not - Drug start date is different to the action date.  The drug start date is the date it is prescribed.  The action date is the date that the action was assigned to that drug.  They are linked by oid and fk2_oid, and there are multiple actions per individual drug prescription.  The action dates can go on for ever if a person is prescribed a drug on repeat.  Paracetamol can be prescribed to someone for a year and over that year there may be many comments/notes and other actions, but only one individual drug prescription.  Not rocket science really.

Comment: Amended original post to better reflect what i require.  Hope this is clearer.

Comment: I changed my answer to show how you can Group by Drug then Check on GH1's Underlay Following Section to bring Group Header to Details row.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!!  Its is presenting another problem with viewing in CRViewer now but from looking it up i dont think that is solvable! :(.  Thanks a lot